# Shopify Ajax API

Tags: ajax, api, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to access the Shopify backend to update a customer's email, phone, and name via Ajax request.
I'm receiving a 404 error. while in postman and in google chrome the values are returned correctly and in postman, I am able to modify the values with PUT type.

my code:

```
let custFN = document.getElementById("customerFirstName").getAttribute("value")  ;
      let custLN = document.getElementById("customerLarstName").getAttribute("value")  ;
      let custEM = document.getElementById("customerEmail").getAttribute("value")  ;
      let custPH = document.getElementById("customerPhone").getAttribute("value")  ;
      let custID = document.getElementById("customerId").getAttribute("value")  ;     
      
let  customerdata = {
          "customer": {
            "id": custID,
            "first_name": custFN ,
            "last_name": custLN,
            "email": custEM,
            "phone": custPH,
             }
      };
       
       var customer_data_json = JSON.stringify(customerdata);

       jQuery.cookie("session", null);
     
       jQuery.ajax({
url:'https://{api key}:{api password}@{mysotre}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/customers/{customer_id}}.json',
type: 'PUT',
cache: false,
data: customer_data_json,
crossDomain: true,
dataType: "JSONP",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(response) {
console.log(response);
},
error: function(response) {
console.log("-------------------------------- <ERROR> --------------------------------");
console.log(response);
console.log("-------------------------------- </ERROR> --------------------------------");
}
});
```

I placed the values noted with {} above.

I have changed to JSONP from JSON to avoid and fix the CORS policy error.
keep in mind that the response readyState is 4.

P.S: As mentioned by Shopify documentation, I created a private app, and did all the steps required to CRUD using API in Shopify are done.

Comment: What is the full URL where request sent?

Comment: if i add it it will redirect to admin panels. this is another problem to discuss its just the ajax function not firing